# JavaScript function evaluating itself and calling itself at the same time

Tags: javascript

I am learning about JavaScript functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

I came across an example that looks similar to this:

`var saySomething = ( function(){console.log("hello")} )();`

I have also seen this in the jQuery source.

I have not found any explanation of this style of function calling/definition on the MDN function [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions).

I know from running the code that it calls itself immediately upon interpretation by the JavaScript engine.

Is this the [Grouping Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) in action? Where it says:

1. First evaluate the body of this function and return it
2. Since the parentheses `()` immediately follow it it gets called ?

Comment: It's called a self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: So i was right on what I thought was going on with the grouping operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" or "IIFE".

The general syntax looks like this:

```
(function(){
// do something here
})():
```

Sometimes you'll see arguments passed in as well. It's basically used to wrap your code so none of your variables leak out into the global namespace.